# Is $\sin z$ a square of a holomorphic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

Is there a holomorphic function $f$ satisfying $(f(z))^2=\sin(z)$ on a nbhd of 0? I know that for these kind of problems it is common to use a logarithm, in this case $g(z):=\exp(L(\sin(z)/2))$ where $L$ is the logarithm. I assume that such a $g$ cannot exist because of the zeros of $\sin z$.

Comment: By $f^2(z)$ do you mean $f(f(z))$ or $(f(z))^2$? $\qquad$

Comment: I mean $(f(z))^2$.

Comment: I've edited the question to say $(f(z))^2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\sin z = f(z)^2$ then $f(0) = 0$ which would mean that $\sin z$ has a zero of (at least) multiplicity $2$ at $z=0$ which it does not.

Comment: (One reason to consider this is that $\sin z\approx z$ close to $z=0$, but there's no holomorphic square root function in that domain.  Or, the winding number of the argument of $\sin z$ when going around a small loop is $1$, but it'd have to be even if $\sin z$ had a square root.  I'm not putting this in a separate answer because it's basically the same as this one.)

Comment: But $1-\cos(z)$ is a square and it only has a zero at 0 of multiplicity 1, or am I missing something?

Comment: @user424862 $1-\cos z$ has a double zero at the origin.

Comment: Indeed, this argument seems to show that *any* odd function is not representable as the square of another (holomorphic) function at the origin, which is kinda nice!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that by $f^2(z)$ you meant $(f(z))^2,$ not $f(f(z)).$ If the latter, I think the answer may be "yes". (Google the phrase "What you have to do twice in order to sin". I think that was the title of a talk someone gave.)

As $z$ approaches $0$ along the positive $x$-axis, $\dfrac d {dz} \sqrt{\sin z}$ approaches $+\infty$ and $\dfrac d {dz} (-\sqrt{\sin z}\,)$ approaches $-\infty.$ If there were a function holomorphic in some neighborhood of $0$ whose square is $\sin z$ within that neighborhood, then on intervals of the form $[0,\varepsilon)$ it would agree with either $+\sqrt{\sin z}$ or $-\sqrt{\sin z}.$ So its derivative could not approach any particular complex number. But the derivative of the proposed holomorphic function would have to approach the value of that function at $0.$ So the answer is no.